# Are general ample divisors on abelian varieties smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

It is well known that in $\mathcal{A}_g$, the space of principally polarized abelian varieties, the general element has a smooth theta divisor (see Andreotti-Mayer, for example).

Now let $\mathcal{A}_g^D$ be the space of polarized abelian varieties of type $D=(d_1,\ldots,d_g)$. Is is true that for general $(A,\mathcal{L})\in\mathcal{A}_g^D$, and a general divisor $L$ that defines $\mathcal{L}$, $L$ is smooth? Is there some reference I can look up?

Comment: Yes, by essentially the same argument: a polarization of type $D$ on $A$ is the pull back of a principal polarization by an appropriate isogeny $\pi : A\rightarrow A'$. Thus the corresponding linear system $|\mathcal{L}|$ contains the pull back of a theta divisor on $A'$, which is smooth as you mention. Therefore a general element of  $|\mathcal{L}|$ is smooth.

Comment: Dear abx, nice answer! Yes you are right, this works perfectly.